# Failed to load PDF document into blob type in my database php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have a dataform form where I upload pdf files into a blob type field, 
my problem is when i want to display it it always gives me the message: Failed to load PDF document. is follow my code:

```
     $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_GET['doc']); 
 $q = mysqli_query($conn, ' SELECT document FROM saisie WHERE code = "'.$doc.'" ');  
 $r= mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);  
 $doc=$r['document'];

 header('Content-Type: application/pdf') ; 
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test.pdf"') ;
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 @readfile($doc) ;
```

Comment: Please read the doc for [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) - It's not what you need here.

Comment: what i need plz

Comment: Did you try `echo $doc;`? Though I'm not sure if that works with blobs. `readfile($filename)` expects a filename as parameter - not the content of the file.

Comment: I tried echo but it does not work ,same result  @Paul Spiege

Comment: So what's the error message now? `echo` works for me.

Comment: Failed to load the PDF document. and in console google chrome i have  this warning: [Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead

Comment: Remove the header declaration and look what PHP errors you get. I might also need to turn on error reporting in PHP.

Comment: he does not give an error

Comment: [how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/5563083)

Comment: i try your function but no error

Comment: @PaulSpiegel for me `echo` works too, but it fits the whole page, I can't read the other information. Is there any parameter to fit it into a windowed size?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script which works fine for me:

```php
<?php

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "test","");

// Read the file and store as blob into DB
$filename = 'doc.pdf';
$fileContents = file_get_contents($filename);

$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into pdf_blob(filename, data) values (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([$filename, $fileContents]);


// Read blob data from DB and output in browser
$stmt = $db->prepare("select filename, data from pdf_blob where filename = ? limit 1");
$stmt->execute([$filename]);
$result = $stmt->fetch();

header('Content-Type: application/pdf') ;
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test.pdf"') ;
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

echo $result['data'];
```

I read a PDF file from the file system with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and store the content into a MySQL BLOB column. After that I read the same data from the DB and simply use `echo` for the output. The header declaration is exactly the same as in your code.

Though I use *PDO* here instead of *mysqli*, it should probably not matter.

Here is my table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `pdf_blob` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `filename` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `data` BLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```